# gradle-4.4: at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting this weird error when re-building the project

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find outer class com/razorpay/Y_$B$ of com/razorpay/Y_$B$$5
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:1079)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.ClassVsInterface.isOuterInterface(ClassVsInterface.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitOuterClass(InterfaceDesugaring.java:246)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:638)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

I don't know what exactly the issue is, this [link](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384) suggests to add

```
android.enableD8.desugaring = true
```

This is my gradle-wrapper-properties

```
#Fri Apr 20 00:53:41 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
android.enableD8.desugaring=true
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4- 
all.zip
```

Still, the issue persists! Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Im seeing the same and this is very likely a gradle tooling bug. You should file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah will do, downgrading to gradle-4.1 fixes this